# How do I find a variable length string between two marker characters in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

This is a very basic regex question, but I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong.

I am attempting to take an input string such as this:

`string exp = @"$a$ + $ab$";`

Match the pattern `$....$` and replace that value in the original string. For example, I want to substitute the number 1 for `$a$` and the number 2 for `$ab$`, so my final string would look like `"1 + 2"`.

What I have setup is the following function:

```
private string SubstituteStandardValues(string exp)
{
    //Find Std values w/Regex
    Match match = Regex.Match(exp, @"/\($.*$\)/s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        foreach (var m in match.Groups)
        {
            //Do string replace logic here!
        }
    }
    return exp;
}
```

My problem is `match` is always `false`, which leads me to believe that my regex is incorrect.

Where have I gone astray? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the /\ for? Also, might want to use a lazy match, not greedy

Comment: Apart from the Regex, a simple `exp.Replace("$a$","1").Replace("$b$","2")` would work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
public string SubstituteStandardValues(string exp)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(exp, @"\$[a-z]+\$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        // replace logic here...
    }

    return exp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex pattern string is this:

```
@"\$[^$]+\$"
```

There are no regex delimiters ("/") in .NET regex and no modifiers ("/s"). Use `RegexOptions` for that.

The `$` means "end-of-string" unless you escape it or it is in a character class.

You need a character class to match "anything but a $" (`[^$]`).

You do not need a group if the *entire match* is what you are interested in.

Answer (score -1):

you're putting a backslash infront of the parenthesis, which means it's looking for the literal "(" and ")".  You must, however, escape the dollar sign.  You're also not using a lazy quantifier.

```
@"/(\$.*?\$)/"
```

Comment: What are the forward slashes for?